# I cannot boot bananapro board possibly because of SD card layout

Tags: sd-card, yocto

I managed to compile a linux distribution thanks to yocto. I have 4 different files which are :

```
bootloader u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin-bananapi-2020.01-r0
kernel uImage--5.4.111-r0-bananapi-20230504112433.bin
rootfs core-image-minimal-bananapi-20230504112433.rootfs.ext4 
device tree sun7i-a20-bananapi--5.4.111-r0-bananapi-20230504112433.dtb
```

I followed directives on https://linux-sunxi.org/Bootable_SD_card

Things that I did are as follows:

1. I made partitions and set filesystems to the partitions. This is the current situation of SD card.

```
label: dos
label-id: 0x65bf9d54
device: /dev/mmcblk0
unit: sectors
/dev/mmcblk0p1 : start=        2048, size=      204800, type=6, bootable
/dev/mmcblk0p2 : start=      206848, size=    60225536, type=83
```

---

2. According to the document flashing boot code is

```
dd if=u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin of=${card} bs=1024 seek=8
```

Instead of above code I used the following:

```
dd if=u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin-bananapi-2020.01-r0 of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=1024 seek=8
```

This is the output:

```
965+1 records in
965+1 records out
494399 bytes (494 kB, 483 KiB) copied, 0.117692 s, 4.2 MB/s
```

**Question: Shouldn't I `dd` it to the first partition (`/dev/mmcblk0p1`)?**

---

3. Then I copied kernel to the first partition in line with the documentation

```
sudo cp uImage--5.4.111-r0-bananapi-20230504112433.bin /mnt/mmcblk0p1
```

---

4. I copied device tree to the first partition

```
sudo cp ~/Documents/shared_with_VB/bananapi/sun7i-a20-bananapi--5.4.111-r0-bananapi-20230504112433.dtb /mnt/mmcblk0p1
```

---

5. I copied rootfs to the second partition

```
sudo cp ~/Documents/shared_with_VB/bananapi/core-image-minimal-bananapi-20230504112433.rootfs.ext4 /mnt/mmcblk0p2
```

---

Then I put the SD card on the board and power the board nothing happened.

**Question: Did I make a mistake, or can someone suggest what steps to take or what to follow?**

Comment: You are probably better asking this on the banana-pi forum.

Comment: @kemal If my answer did solve the problem, please mark it, so the question doesn't remain unsolved. If it doesn't, please comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to first Question**

No. The first partition is a FAT volume where the U-Boot will find the kernel to start and the device tree used. But the U-Boot itself needs to be placed somehere else. A 8 kByte offset from the starting of the SD card is a common place where a first stage bootloader (SPL?) will find it. That's inside an unused area between partition table and start of the first partition.

**Answer to second question**

Your rootfs file is an ext4 file system image, so you need to flash the image:

```
sudo dd if=~/Documents/shared_with_VB/bananapi/core-image-minimal-bananapi-20230504112433.rootfs.ext4 of=/mnt/mmcblk0p2 bs=1M
```

If you were watching the system start on a serial console, you would probably had seen it complain about a boring rootfs with only one useless file (the image copied instead of `dd`ing it.